# Prove an inequality or minimum of polynomial.

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I have problem proving that, for $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $2\leq y$,
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4-x}\leq \frac{7}{8}(y-x)+\frac{1}{2(y-x)+2}.
\end{align}
What I have done is that I checked, online, the graph of the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{7}{8}(y-x)+\frac{1}{2(y-x)+2}-\Big[\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4-x}\Big]$$ for $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $2\leq y$ and I found the eniquality is correct. Now, how to prove the inequality technically.

Comment: You could potentially look for extremal points in the interior using gradient equals zero, and then focus on seros on the boundary (where the problem reduces to one dimension). But I don't see this as being efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $2-x=a$ and $y-2=b.$ Then, $$\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2+a}\leq\dfrac{7}{8}(a+b)+\dfrac{1}{2(a+b)+2},$$ which is equivalent to: $$\dfrac{2b+a}{(2+a)(1+a+b)}\leq\dfrac{3a+7b}{4}.$$

But this is immediate if you just expand everything and remember that $a,b$ are non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\frac{2a}{a+1}$ and $y=b+2$, where $a$ and $b$ are non-negatives.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\frac{8y-4x-8}{(4-x)(y-x+1)}\leq7y-3x+8$$  and I got 
$$7a^3b^2+19a^3b+28a^2b^2+12a^3+10a^2b+35ab^2+94a^2+14b^2+163ab+202a+82b+132\geq0$$